# Sending email to Mobile phone via Mailgun doesn't work

Tags: mailgun

I am new to Mail gun.  I am using it as a mail relay. Sending to email boxes works just fine, but when I send emails to mobile phones, they don't go through. Logs say the email bounces back, then says completed, but no text comes through on the phones.  I am using 10 digit phone `number@carrier domain.com`.  Example `2223334567@messaging.sprintpcs.com`.  I researched the issue and found no articles on the support site.  I tried submitting a ticket, but the Submit a ticket button doesn't do anything.

Comment: Is `2223334567@messaging.sprintpcs.com` supposed to be a valid email address? Never heard of that. How is the recipient supposed to check and see the email?

Comment: @JeremyThille: That way of sending SMS messages works fine. See  https://20somethingfinance.com/how-to-send-text-messages-sms-via-email-for-free/ I use the technique frequently for notifications from automated processes when errors happen that shouldn't (monitoring apps for certain backup operations, for instance), so that I get notification to my phone as well as email.